# Async version of jquery.min.js

Tags: asynchronous, xhtml, script-tag

My blogger Blog have this thing embedded on the theme.
Well, Google Webmasters tools says that I need to load this thing "asynchronously"
I have searched the web for an async  version of Google-Hosted jquery.min.js but no luck.
I also tried using a function but since it is a link I can't use it.

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js
```

I have tried:

```
<script async src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.0/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"/>
```

No luck. XML parser says that I need to put a " = " but that thing is already written.

My doctype

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html expr:dir='data:blog.languageDirection' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xmlns:b='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/b' xmlns:data='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/data' xmlns:expr='http://www.google.com/2005/gml/expr'>
```

Comment: um? :( I didn't get it

Comment: `<script async="async" ... >`

Comment: Thanks, If you could formulate an answer I could give you will mark it.

Comment: XML (and therefore XHTML) requires every attribute to have a value. Hence you have to use the form `x="y"`. Just using `x` is only valid in HTML (and only for boolean attributes).

Answer (score 1):

The rendering engine does not care about the value, it looks for the presence of the attribute so set it to itself to make the validator happy.

```
<script async="async"   ... >
```

Comment: But to be valid HTML, the value must either be an empty string or the name of attribute: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/#boolean-attributes (`x` is equivalent to `x=""` I believe).